# Bootstrap Dropdown Not Working Still

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

After much searching, I am still having trouble getting the Bootstrap dropdown to toggle and actually select items from the dropdown.  The Bootstrap site says to include the .show class, but I have not had any luck with this either.  Many of the examples I see here do not seem to work for me.  Help, please!

This is my code:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.jumbotron {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.7em;
    margin-bottom: .8em;
}

.question {
    margin-top: 2em;
    padding-right: 6em;
    padding-left: 6em;
}

.buttonContainer {
    margin: 3em;
    text-align: center;
}

.button {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/main.css">



</head>

<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 id="header">
            Post-Surgery Survey
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container question">
        <h2>What kind of surgery did you have?</h2>
        <div class="dropdown surgeryType">
            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"> Select One
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hip Replacement</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Knee Replacement</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container question">
        <h2>How old are you?</h2>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"> Select One
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Under 50</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">50-65</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">66-80</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Over 80</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container question">
        <h2>What kind of medication were you given?</h2>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Tylenol</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Celebrex</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Oxycodone</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Oxycotin</label>
        </div>

    </div>


    <div class="container question">
        <h2>Do you feel you were given enough medication?</h2>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"> Select One
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Too much</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Just right</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Not enough</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container question">
        <h2>How well was your pain controlled on a scale of 1-10?</h2>
        <p>1 being the most pain, 10 being the least.</p>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"> Select One
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">9</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">10</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container question">
        <h2>Were you satisfied with your pain control?</h2>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"> Select One
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Yes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">No</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="buttonContainer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg submit">Submit</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: so when you select the dropdown option, it doesn't do anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you're trying to do. Right now all your hrefs are merely anchor tags. They don't go anywhere. `<li><a href="#">Under 50</a></li>`, for example. When you select an option in a dropdown, note how the page jumps a bit? That's the anchor tag being selected jumping you to the top of the same page.

If there was an actual URL, you'd go to that page. I suspect that's not what you're trying to achieve, though. This looks more like a form, in which case you probably don't want `.dropdown-toggle` or `data-toggle="dropdown"` assigned to buttons. You'd want a simple select element, no?

```
<select class="form-control" id="some-id">
  <option>Select an option</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding!  Yes, I do not want to go to a URL, I do want a simple select element.

Comment: No problem, that's good to hear! If that solves the issue, would you please mark the answer as accepted?